Preservation of strict log-concavity under convolution
I have spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to prove or disprove any of this. I am aware that a similar question was posted in 2014, but since I couldn't make anything out of the two sources provided, I wanted to take my chance.
I am looking at the convolution of a Gaussian random vector with either a log-concave or strictly log-concave random vector. Is the resulting random vector strictly log-concave in any of the above cases? Further, is there any source where I can find this result and maybe even a proof?
Thank you for any insight.
Link to the old question: Does convolution preserve strict log-concavity?

Please link the old post, or provide it in a comment.

It is known that convolution preserves log-concavity, see section "Operations preserving log-concavity " in this Wikipedia page.

@Amir Thank you for taking your time to answer. I already found out that the resulting vector will be log-concave but it is essential for my use that is even strictly log-concave. I don't think this is mentioned on Wikipedia. Best regards, Jacob

What do you mean by the convolution of two random vectors?

A more correct/precise statement would be the sum of two independent random vectors, one being Gaussian and the other having a (strict) log-concave density function.

Please provide the mathematical statement in the OP as convolution is a term often used for two real-valued functions, not two random vectors.
